# How do I redirect system console output to a file?

Tags: logging, freebsd

I'm dealing with a strange issue that's causing the CPU to halt on a machine when a certain piece of hardware is used.

The CPU freezes, the machine reboots, and there is no account of what happened afterwards. No syslogs, no crash log, nothing.

But before the crash, the system spews a massive amount of text to the console very rapidly. I want to read this text to see if it can help diagnose what's wrong.

How do I get freeBSD setup such that this console output is redirected to a file? 
I found an old topic over at their forums: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/tip-log-console-messages.10090/ where someone managed to do it in 2010. But doing that with the current iteration of the OS will just crash the syslogd.

The output i'm interested in is all the kernel messages and so on, which by default displays in slightly brighter text format in the system's console. Messages show by default for example when connecting a keyboard while the system is running.

Answer (score 0):

More careful study of https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-syslog.html is required.

In addition, the location of the command within the file is important due to the way this config file is setup.

You should get what you want by adding the entry:

```
console.info                                /var/log/console.log
```

to the file `/etc/syslog.conf`, right after the entry for `*.emerg`. Afterwards, execute `/etc/rc.d/syslogd restart`

Comment: Another technique that can be helpful when trying to capture syslog activity from a system that crashes or locks up spontaneously is to use remote syslogging.